# Can't format or delete any files on SD card

Tags: format, sd-card, fdisk

I have a 16 GB SD card i'm trying to format for use.
In Windows if I try to format it says *Windows was unable to complete the format*, and in Linux when I do `fdisk -l -u`, fdisk just hangs when the SD card is in. GParted also hangs if I try to open it up.

There are also some files on it, if I delete these files, unplug the SD card and plug it back in, the files reappear.

I tried using SDFormatter from [www.sdcard.org](http://www.sdcard.org), which says it's write-protected. But I have already tried flipping the switch on the SD card, which didn't change anything.

How can I format this thing?

Comment: Might be a silly suggestion, but does your SD card have a physical read-only switch on the outside?

Comment: @BenMordecai it does. I've tried switching it back and forth, neither work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is actually a Micro/Mini SD card in an SD card adapter, try to get a different adapter. I had 3 Kingston adapters that failed exactly like that - they became read-only.

Also try to do these operations in another computer/card reader. It is possible you have issues with your reader.

If these things don't help, I think this card is somehow defective and it's time to trash it.